# Rails request.xhr? returns 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to detect whether request is xhr or not in ApplicationController by using

```
request.xhr?
```

It always returns 0.

But headers tell otherwise;

```
request.headers["X-Requested-With"]  ==> "XMLHttpRequest"
@_env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ==> "XMLHttpRequest"
```

What am I missing?

version is Rails 4.0.0

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: @zishe it is a remote DELETE request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`request.xhr?` always returns `Object` or `nil`, not `true` or `false`, since it's based on regexp pattern matching (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-xml_http_request-3F)).

In Ruby, any value other than `false` and `nil` is a truthy value (as is the `0` returned by `request.xhr?`), so the response is correct.